# What is the closed form of the sequence $\{-\frac12,\frac19,\frac{13}{100},\frac{71}{588},\frac{71}{648},\frac{1447}{14520},\frac{617}{6760},...\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am trying to find the closed form of the following sequence:

$$ \left\lbrace -\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{9} , \frac{13}{100} , \frac{71}{588} , \frac{71}{648} , \frac{1447}{14520} , \frac{617}{6760} , \frac{1061}{12600} , ... \right\rbrace \tag{1}$$

These form the coefficients $a_k$ with $k=1,3,5,...$ of a power series expansion of the following form:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1,3,5,...}^\infty a_k x^k = a_1 x + a_3 x^3 + a_5 x^5 + ..., \tag{2}$$

for which I wish to find a closed form. I could not find anything in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) nor in [OEIS](http://oeis.org). Here is a plot of $(1)$:

[image]

Note that these coefficients were found numerically, and the rational forms given above agree up to at least 15 significant digits. If needed I can probably obtain any desired coefficient, although the precision may decrease.

**EDIT**:

Here is some context, as suggested in the comments. This sequence arises when trying to solve the following integral:

$$I(x) = \frac{1}{2^9\pi^5} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau \left\lbrace \frac{1}{1+\tau^2} \arctan^2 \frac{\tau}{x} + \frac{x}{x^2 + \tau^2} \arctan^2 \tau \right\rbrace \tag{3}$$

with $x>0$. I managed to obtain the following form numerically:

$$I(x) = \frac{1}{2^{13} \pi^4} + \frac{1}{2^{10}\pi^6} \tanh^{-1}(x) \left\lbrace \log(x) - \tanh^{-1}(x) + 2\log 2 \right\rbrace + \frac{1}{2^9 \pi^6} \sum_{k=1,3,5,...} a_k x^k. \tag{4}$$

So finding a closed form for $(1)$ would give me the exact solution of the integral $I(x)$. Note that the integral exhibits the curious symmetry $I(x) = I(1/x)$.

Comment: Presumably you know something about the power series...the more information you provide the greater the chance someone will see a pattern.

Comment: @lulu Good point, and done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{-1}{2k^2}+\frac1{2k}\left(1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{(k-1)/2}\right)$$
Where $k$ is the same odd number as in the question

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow! Nice find. How did you come up with this?

Comment: The denominators contained $k^2$, and the second difference of$k^2a_k$ was $3/4,5/12,7/24,9/40,11/60,...$