# Is there a closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k}{1+2k}x^{1+2k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

As a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761254/what-is-the-closed-form-of-the-sequence-frac12-frac19-frac13100-frac), I would like to know if there exists a closed form for this sum:

$$f(x) \equiv \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k}{2k + 1} x^{2k+1}. \tag{1}$$

with $x$ real and positive. There are some [similar identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Harmonic_numbers) in the wikipedia article, but I could not relate them to this sum. I would imagine that $\tanh^{-1}$ and/or $\log$ would be involved, but that's just a guess.

Comment: We have $$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-t^k}{1-t} \, \mathrm{d}t \right) x^{2k} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2t}\right) \, \mathrm{d}t=-\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1-x^2}.$$ So it is reasonable to expect that $f(x)$ will involve dilogarithm.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, thanks. I actually just realized that, and I was able to solve the question. I will post an answer in a short while.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, we have:

$$f'(x) = \frac{\log (1+x^2)}{x^2-1}, \tag{2}$$

which Mathematica can integrate and gives:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4} \left\lbrace 2 \log^2 (1-x) - 2\log (1-x)\log(x-1) + \left( \log(x-1) + \log(x+1) \right) \left( \log (x-1) + \log(x+1) + 2\log 2 \right) - 2 \text{Li}_2 \left( \frac{1-x}{2} \right) - 2 \text{Li}_2 \left( \frac{1+x}{2} \right) + \text{constant} \right\rbrace. \tag{3}$$

I fixed the constant numerically by comparing $(1)$ and $(3)$ at some value of $x$. It was easy to guess the closed form of the constant:

$$\text{constant} = \pi^2 - 2 i \pi \log 2. \tag{4}$$